# Creating forms that save to the database & can be viewed in the admin

Tags: form, plugin-sproutforms

is it possible to create forms that save to the DB & a new screen in admin to see the submissions?

Is there a user created forms module (like gravity forms) for Craft?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For now, you can create forms and create entries through the plugin [Guest Entries](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/GuestEntries).

In Guest Entries, entries are disabled by default.

Sprout also has a [plugin for creating forms](http://sprout.barrelstrengthdesign.com/craft-plugins/forms), that is currently in beta.

Is there anything specific you are looking for, or would you just like to be able to receive submissions from site users?

If you give some more information, we might be able to give you some better advice, but the Forms Market is still pretty thin.

Would you say those forms are always the same in the context of a site? You don't need a form builder for that (?), unless they are always changing and adding things. Even then, you can make a rudimentary form builder by using Matrix.

The notifications part has to be be added by a custom plugin. You can hook into the [onSaveEntry hook](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/events-reference#entries-onSaveEntry), for example.

I built a notification plugin that does that, which sends of an e-mail and a sms to the site owner when entries are added through Guest Entries.

Subscribing to MailChimp is also fairly easy. You can have a look at the [MailChimp Subscribe plugin](https://github.com/aelvan/mailchimp-subscribe-craft) as an example.

Comment: Thanks Fred, so a typical requirement is we might have a set of entries for say retirement homes, and each one wants a form to apply for info.  Those applications would need to be saved to DB, email notify a few people, email a "Thanks then" response to the user and sign up the user to Mailchimp if they ticked.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks.  This is great.  So can be done, make custom functionality like this in a plugin.  no existing plugin like GForms. I might make that as a plugin to get a feel for things.  I'm intrigued by "you can make a rudimentary form builder using Matrix" gonna go home & try that : )

Answer (score 1):

Yes but you would need a to build a plugin to do so. The [Pixel and Tonic Contact Form](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/ContactForm/) is a good place to start or you could build your own.

As an alternative you could create a "[saveEntry](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/entry-form)" form which would save the content form submissions as entries or use the plugins like Fred suggested.